# Rollback two commits. Reapply second commit. Branch and apply first commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

In my project, I've recently made two commits. The commits are on different sets of files. I've also pushed these commits remotely. Something like the following-

```
git commit file-a file-b -m "first commit of new features"
git commit file-c file-d -m "second commit of new features"
git push -u origin master
```

I would like to do the following-

1. Rollback the master to before the first commit and then apply
   *only* the second commit.
2. Create a feature branch at this point
   and apply the second commit (it should have the first commit too).

Is this possible to achieve in a simple way? I've thought about creating and using a patch file with git diff, but I thought I'd check first if there's a better way.

Comment: Read about interactive rebase and cherry-picking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create a feature branch at this point and apply the second commit (it should have the first commit too).

Simply create a feature branch right where your `master` currently is:

```
git branch feature_branch
```

> Rollback the master to before the first commit and then apply only the second commit.

```
git reset --hard @~2
```

Re-order commits on the feature branch

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase -i master
# switch second and first commit order
```

Then reset master to feature_branch~1 (which is the second commit)

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard feature_branch~1
```

Finally, push everything

```
git push --force origin master
git push -u origin feature_branch
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I used `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to switch the order.